# Was bedeutet "hinterlegt" und "gepflegt"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Was bedeutet, dass bestimmte Daten in einem System hinterlegt und gepflegt werden?

Beispiele:

1. *Die steuernden Angaben zum Mahnwesen werden hier hinterlegt und gepflegt.*
2. *Steigern Sie Ihre Effizienz, da viele Infos wie Adressen, Material oder Leistungen nur einmal hinterlegt und gepflegt werden müssen.*

Vielen Dank im Voraus.

Answer (score 5):

**Hinterlegen** bedeutet in diesem Zusammenhang einfach "speichern": Die Daten werden an dieser Stelle gespeichert.

**Pflegen** bedeutet "verändern", "aktualisieren". Adressdaten beispielsweise ändern sich hin und wieder, zum Beispiel ein Ansprechpartner oder eine Telefonnummer.